# XCode can't find main.m file after rename project

Tags: ios, xcode, build, rename

I have strange but probably quite simple problem with rename Xcode project. I did everything like this guy show on this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRnVjtNLLLk

So I change project name in identity and type, change schema name, change app folder name and I change location of files to new folder. I also change properties in build settings and everything seems to look ok, but I have this error when I try to build app:

> Apple LLVM 8.0
>
> 'myPathToProject/oldProjectName/newProjectName/main.m'Error clang: error: no such file or directory:

This directory don't exist. 
I don't know why xcode looking for main.m file in this no existing directory and I don't know how and where to add a correct path to the main.m Any ideas?